# Как реализовать бесконечный цикл WebDriver на php?

Tags: php

Как с помощью  WebDriver на php реализовать цикл проверки и получения содержимого div?

Интересует реализация таким образом, чтобы не нужно было закрывать и открывать исполняемую страницу каждый раз заново...

Спасибо!

Comment: А что конкретно вы не знаете как сделать? Бесконечный цикл на php это while(true) {}.

Comment: пробовал, отваливается по таймауту

Comment: set_time_limit(0); пробовали?

Comment: нет, но взял на вооружение, решил путем изменения, не знаю на сколько это правильно и будет стабильно работать, но работает ini_set('max_execution_time', 60*60*24);